# Send one invalid email response to sender

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, email-bounces

I discovered that my postfix/dovecot configuration isn't rejecting emails.  If a person sends an email to an invalid email-address, it just drops it.  I am fine with this behavior since I think it discourages spammers from mining emails (I have had some success).  Recently a person I did not want to talk to emailed an address I cut off and didn't receive a response back.  It would have saved me some problems if they knew to call me instead of sending 50+ emails.  How would I configure Dovecot/postfix to send a message back to a sender of an email address and then limit this 1 per domain or unique email.

Debian Stable

Linux 3.6.5-linode47

Dovecot 1.2.15

Postfix 2.7.1

PSQL - backend if that matters

Comment: I didn't get your configuration. Probably because you didn't provide one. Your solution - as far as I understood it - is to disable catch-all. Dropping mail does *not* discourage spammers. Instead it encourage them to send you more.

Comment: <Quote>I didn't get your configuration. Probably because you didn't provide one.</Quote>This was unnecessary, which files would you like and I will love to post them for you.  I am not looking to disable catch-all since I like this behavior.  I am trying to add a one time exception.  They do send me more spam because of this, but it contained in one email instead of me having to deal with a common name attack where I get alice@mydomain.com, andy@mydomain.com, annie@mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Postfix out-of-the-box. Because this is a too localized and very uncommon setup. Probably you want "Greylisting" and you didn't told us. This on the other hand is very common and you can find many implementations for Postfix out here.

If you really want to do this one-time-reject (not defer, because this would be greylisting), then you have to develop a new solution yourself. See the [SMTP Access Policy Delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) documentation for that.